# How to remove Windows 10-11 notifications on dismissing from screen?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, notification-area

When a notification arrives in Windows, it shows up on screen. Is there any way that if I dismiss that notification(via either swipping or using X sign) from screen then it also gets removed from the Action Bar?

Because right now, even after I dismiss the notification from screen by swiping it right, it still stays in Action Bar.

The feature that I'm asking for is default behaviour in Android - if we're on some app and a notification arrives, on swiping it right removes it altogether from the notifications bar.

Comment: Many notifications.  What ones are you trying to dismiss.

Comment: @John Not sure if that was rhetorical one or not :D. But I'd answer anyway - I'd like the notifications gone which I swipe from screen when they show up.

Comment: The reason I asked which notifications is that when I dismiss regular notifications (Windows 10 and 11) the notifications are gone

Comment: @John in my case all kinds the notifications(System, Apps, Messengers etc) stay in the action bar even after dismissing from screen. I have to go to action bar and dismiss them again from there to get rid of them.

Comment: I thought about this. Windows is not Android.  So in Windows we must dismiss the notifications and that works.